# Winmerge: How to Disable the 3-way dialog?

Tags: winmerge

Recently, and without my consent, my Winmerge went from 2.14 to 2.16.  And the horrible behavior and UI changes that go along with it.  (how it happened, I don't know, I think a windows update)

How do I get back to the better functioning operation of 2.14?  I know they *think* all these are great improvements... but they're not for everyone.

It's fine when used with a source control that only launches it with two files.  But I use it in standalone mode a lot.

When dragging to the new multi-selection dialog, it usually misses, and puts the files in 1 and 3, missing #2.  And there is no easy way to undo that. I have to drop the mouse, loose the cursor, highlight the field and delete it. I ONLY want to compare two files.

Furthermore, why does it populate the dialog with my last compare? Did no one realize that after I did a compare and merge, I don't need to do it again??  Combine the fact that the files are now already pre-populated with the lack of precision in the above paragraph, and it's super-annoying have three files appear.

When dragging anywhere into the client area, version 2.14 ALWAYS placed the first drag in position 1, and the second in position 2 (unless you were super precise about where you wanted it to go).

All my searches come up with how to hack the code and rebuild it, or how it integrates with VSCode, which I don't/won't use, something about how it works with GIT, which is not standalone mode.

I'm glad I didn't contribute in this case.

How can I make it behave the way it did in 2.14 which was better?

Did they not think to make these annoying new "features" configurable, somewhere in the options?